ECharts: How to Handle Large Discrepancies in Data Values in a Stacked Bar Chart
I'm having trouble with the scale of my stacked bar chart in ECharts when there's a significant discrepancy between data values. The issue is that the chart doesn't represent the smaller values well when there's a large outlier.
Here's a simplified version of my ECharts configuration:
option = {
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    axisPointer: {
      type: 'shadow' // 'shadow' as default; can also be 'line' or 'shadow'
    }
  },
  legend: {},
  grid: {
    left: '3%',
    right: '4%',
    bottom: '3%',
    containLabel: true
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: [
      "Activity", "Segment", "Branch", "Filled Contact", "Mailing Contact",
      "Contacted Clients", "Clients with Email", "Clients with Call",
      "Clients with Visit", "Clients with Telegram Response",
      "Clients with Quote", "Clients with Negotiation",
      "Clients with Billing", "Billing vs Potential"
    ]
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Completed',
      color: 'green',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'total',
      label: {
        show: true
      },
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series'
      },
      data: [
        0, // Activity
        257, // Segment
        244, // Branch
        148, // Filled Contact
        50, // Mailing Contact
        61, // Contacted Clients
        0, // Clients with Email
        43, // Clients with Call
        0, // Clients with Visit
        0, // Clients with Telegram Response
        34, // Clients with Quote
        13, // Clients with Negotiation
        47, // Clients with Billing
        1703515.66 // Billing vs Potential
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Not Completed',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'total',
      color: 'red',
      label: {
        show: true
      },
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series'
      },
      data: [
        327, // Activity
        70, // Segment
        83, // Branch
        177, // Filled Contact
        275, // Mailing Contact
        266, // Contacted Clients
        327, // Clients with Email
        284, // Clients with Call
        327, // Clients with Visit
        327, // Clients with Telegram Response
        293, // Clients with Quote
        314, // Clients with Negotiation
        305, // Clients with Billing
        3298438.39 // Billing vs Potential
      ]
    }
  ]
};

As you can see, there's a significant gap between the "Billing vs Potential" values compared to the other categories. This causes the smaller values to be almost invisible on the chart.
Question: How can I adjust the ECharts configuration so that all bars are visually represented, even when there's a large discrepancy in the values? Is there a way to apply a logarithmic scale or any other method to improve the visualization in this scenario?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

You need a third axis to display those large numbers (calculated values) as they are in a different scale than the previous values (which look like counts).  So, you would have, X-Axis with your categories for counts and the Y1-Axis for the actual counts and Y2-axis for the calculated values - Not sure why you want to represent these in the graph (as they represent different things) but that's just an idea.  Sample multiple y-axis charts: https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=multiple-y-axis

@blurfus Thank you for your help and for dedicating your time to assist me. I was able to understand how to resolve the issue using the percentiles for "Completed" and "Not Completed". By applying these percentiles to the bars, they now appear uniform.
I appreciate the guidance!

Awesome... feel free to write up your own answer for others in the community to benefit from your newly-acquired knowledge :)
